# I2C Level translation and isolation

Tags: i2c, isolation

I have a Teensy I2C bus driving a PCA9306, which happily talks to multiple ATMEGA32PBs on separate cards connected to a backplane.

Some of the cards require isolation and work on a lower voltage. For this reason, I have an isolated DC-DC converter and an ISO1540DR doing the I2C level translation from the 5V side of the PCA9306 back down to 3.3V and providing isolation. So the order of devices looks like:

Teensy <3.3V> PCA9306 <5V> ISO1540DR <3.3V> ATMEGA328P

The PCA9306 doesn't seem to like driving the ISO1540DR - is there some way around this or a more suitable replacement I could use in place of the ISO1540DR?

**Edit:**

What I have just realized is that I think that side 2 of the ISO1540DR may be better suited to the backplane side, and side 1 to the microcontroller since side 2 can sink/source 100mA and side 1 just 20mA.

Teensy side PCA9306:
[image: Teensy side I2C]

ATMEGA side I2C:

[image: ATMEGA I2C]

[PCA9306 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/scps113)

[ISO1540DR datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ISO1540)

Comment: Data sheet links for the PCA and ISO devices needed (likely).

Comment: "Doesn't seem to like" does not tell us anything useful. What exactly is the problem? Do you have oscilloscope traces? Isn't an effective pull-up resistance of 1.35 kΩ rather strong?

Comment: The PCA09306 is identical with the [LSF0102](https://www.ti.com/product/LSF0102); the latter's web site has links to more application notes.

Comment: Following the guidelines in this [document](https://www.ti.com/lit/slva689), I think the 2.7kΩ pull-up resistors are in the right range for 100KHz, standard mode I2C? 

I will try and get some oscilloscope traces later today.

Comment: @CL Also, the datasheet for the LSF0102 doesn't suggest any pull-up values above 1705Ω - see page 14. Granted, that may be a little on the strong side anyway.

Comment: Trying an ADUM1250 in the place of the ISO1540D seems to be working so far. More to come.

Comment: The pullups on both sides of the LSF are in parallel. The datasheet suggests high currents to achieve high frequencies; 0.1 MHz does not need that.

Comment: There's a pull up on the clock line and a pull up on the data line on each side–both 2.7kΩ so I'm not sure how that makes them parallel/1.35kΩ effective?